# Setting up server access - ports? CORS?

Tags: ember.js

My Ember app works great on the local computer.  I can load the Ember page from another PC, and separately, the back end data using a browser (e.g. [here](http://192.168.1.12:12345/editor/articles)), but Ember cannot; it states ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and retrieves no data to populate the lists/dropdowns/etc with.

Initially I'd had a ton of trouble with PUT messages even on the local, and wound up setting up a CORS rule to try to enable everything, but even that's not working here.

What's going on?  Why can't Ember get the data that the same browser, in another tab, has zero trouble with?

Comment: Can you look at Network tab in your browser's Developer Tools and see where the request is going to?

Answer (score 1):

It's not Ember can't get data. It's browser does not allow to send requests to other domains. Not all requests, though. Some "simple" (limited to GET, HEAD and POST methods and small set of allowed headers) requests could work. [MDN has a big article about CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). In order to fix this, your backend should accept OPTIONS method and include following headers in responses:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://frontend.domain
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
```

Depending on a language/framework that you are using for backend development, you may found libraries/addons/plugins that help in managing CORS headers. I suggest to use those.

Answer (score 0):

Oooh that was stupid of me... The tutorial I started with (giving me the ability to route to a REST sub-route) had a host override in application.js of 127.0.0.1  Which doesn't work from non-localhost of course.

That's a thing to check: Does app/adapter/application.js have an entry for "host" and what is it?